# Sorting + Inserting Values

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I have two problems I'm trying to solve.

First, I'm trying to sort by column AP (this column contains a 1 for every row where column AI is not blank).
The code is supposed to sort so that anytime column AP = 1, the rows that have a 1 appear at the bottom.
Unfortunately, this keeps the rows with a 1 in the middle, and doesn't logically order by putting the zeroes at the top and the ones at the bottom.

```vb
Sub SortSheet()
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A2:AP" & lastrow).Sort key1:=Range("AP2:AP" & lastrow), _
   order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo

End Sub
```

Second, when we sort by column AP, I want to insert three blank rows between where the sorted rows change from 0 to 1.
So in other words, if the first 5 rows are 0 and the 6th row is a 1, I want to insert three blank rows above row 6.

Comment: `xlAscending` perhaps? `xlDescending` would not put `1` at the bottom.

Comment: Buahahaha...dumb question but any idea why descending would layer the order to be 0, 1, 0 ?  That seems to work now though .

Comment: Do you have a mixture of numbers and text-that-looks-like-numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to paste column AP as values before sorting (if they are linked to a cell). The code correctly sorted AP for me.

Here's the full code

```
Sub SortSheet()
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim firstzero As Range
Dim x As Long
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A2:AP" & lastrow).Copy
Range("A2:AP" & lastrow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Range("A2:AP" & lastrow).Sort key1:=Range("AP2:AP" & lastrow), _
    order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo

Range("AP2:AP" & lastrow).Find(0).Select

For x = 1 To 3
   ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
      Selection.Copy
      Selection.Insert Shift:=xlUp
      Application.CutCopyMode = False
      Selection.ClearContents

Next x


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks.  This gets me halfway there.  Does anyone know of an easy way to separate the rows that start with 0 and 1 now that the sorting works?  I'm trying to insert 3 blank rows inbetween where the sorted numbers change just so there's a clear visual gap for the user.

Comment: See my edit post. I added in a copy/paste as values as well as how to insert 3 blank rows.